# DotCMS all requests fail

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, cms

I'm running Ubuntu Server:

```
# uname -a
Linux host-38sigregt 4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
```

with DotCMS 5.0.3 on its embedded instance of Tomcat 8.5.32, configured to hit a local instance of PostgreSQL 10.6:

```
# psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
```

This runs on OpenJDK 8.

I've followed the installation procedure here:

https://dotcms.com/docs/latest/installing-from-release

but all web requests silently fail on the client side, and on the server side the logs are flooded with messages like this:

```
13:47:56.025  WARN  cache.LegacyContentTypeCacheImpl - Structure with inode: 'host' not found in db
13:47:56.027  WARN  web.HostWebAPIImpl - Content Index is fouled up, need to try db: Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[jW
PklQWCTuWnXaHsidwH1w][working_20190308122136][0]: RemoteTransportException[[a2e07940-4a77-4937-9e50-470504ff25e9][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[
phase/query]]]; nested: QueryShardException[No mapping found for [moddate] in order to sort on]; }
13:47:56.029  ERROR business.HostAPIImpl - Content Type with id:'Host' not found
com.dotcms.contenttype.exception.NotFoundInDbException: Content Type with id:'Host' not found
13:47:56.029  ERROR filters.ThreadNameFilter - Unable to retrieve current request host for URI /
13:47:56.030  ERROR filters.CookiesFilter - Exception processing Cookies
javax.servlet.ServletException: Content Type with id:'Host' not found
```

I've tried to research this issue but have come up dry. I've [cross-posted to the DotCMS Github page](https://github.com/dotCMS/core/issues/16192).

Answer (score 0):

So, the likely culprit is that DotCMS requires Java 8, and I had been running OpenJDK 10, which caused a bunch of persistence-related `NoClassDefFound` errors, particularly regarding the activation library. Purging 10 and installing 8, purging the entire database and DotCMS instance and starting over again resulted in a successful instance.